# Is there a framework for zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

At my office we currently use ZF1, and we're looking to use ZF2.

It takes us *ages* to put together simple websites because ZF just doesn't seem organised enough - it's almost a non-framework in my opinion.

Anyway, I was wondering if anyone's built a more 'standard' sort of framework on top, or skeleton application that is friendly to use and well documented - one that has all the kind of standard stuff you'd find in other more simple frameworks like CI/Cake/Symphony etc.

The reason I ask is because I don't think there's any way I can convince my boss that we should use something else, and also I think it would benefit the rest of the team hugely if the whole process could be simplified a bit.

Cheers,
John.

Comment: You answered your own question. For simple jobs use simple tools. Can't help you convince your boss, though.

Comment: Perhaps this is a crap question :/

Comment: Quite a "crap" question that says a lot more about you and the team you work with then it does about Zend Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post on this instead.. thought it might be more useful in that format :)

http://john-hunt.com/2013/03/08/php-frameworks-a-serious-issue/